# Using Regex in JS to filter Strings/URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

Im using an Array that contains several URLs, including http://www.example.com.

Now im using document.URL to check if I'm on one of those sites. If I am, it should perform various actions. However, I do want to perform the same actions on http://www.example.com?params=something too.

Here is my try to solve it.

```
    for(var l=0;l<urlList.length;l++) {
                var url = urlList[l];
                if(document.URL == url || document.URL == (url + '\?.*' ) {
```

What am I doing wrong? How to use that regex Expression correctly (if it is the right expression)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be sufficient to use indexOf:

```
    for(var l=0;l<urlList.length;l++) {
            var url = urlList[l];
            if(document.URL.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
```

Or "normalize" it a bit with regex first. This strips off the http:// and/or www sees if the urls both start the same:

```
    var re = /https?:\/\/(www.)?/;
    for(var l=0;l<urlList.length;l++) {
            var url = urlList[l];
            if(document.URL.replace(re, '').indexOf(url.replace(re, '')) === 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, two very elegant solutions.

Out of curiosity: Any chance my idea would have worked as well with some fixes? 

I checked on http://regexr.com/ and /\?.*/ should have been right. Why didnt it work the way I tried to use it?

Comment: You cannot use the equality `==` operator with regexps. `==` compares strings literally. You have to use one of the regexp methods such as `test` or `exec` or one of the string methods such as `match`.